# Retrieve data from a different fields, where a landmark is a symbol

Tags: xslt

i have data, which looks like:

```
<line id="1">
<field id="1">324</field id="1">
<field id="2">abc</field id="2">
.................................
.................................
.................................
<field id="11">324321</field id="11">
<field id="12"
 ><![CDATA[6256812+0000140000000990000000000009900000000004058002C]]></field>
</line id="1">
<line id="2">
<field id="1">324</field id="1">
<field id="2">abc</field id="2">
.................................
.................................
.................................
<field id="8">324321</field id="11">
<field id="9"
 ><![CDATA[6256813+0000040000000890000000000008900000000003648002C]]></field>
</line id="2">
<line id="3">
<field id="1">324fsf</field id="1">
<field id="2">abcdf</field id="2">
.................................
.................................
.................................
<field id="12">32432s1</field id="11">
<field id="13"
 ><![CDATA[6256812+0000060000000750000000000007500000000003074002C]]></field>
</line id="3">
<line id="4">
<field id="1">3fsfa24</field id="1">
<field id="2">abasc</field id="2">
.................................
.................................
.................................
<field id="18">32fasf4321</field id="11">
<field id="19"
 ><![CDATA[6256837+0000010000000650000000000006500000000002664003C]]></field>
</line id="5">
```

I need to take number before landmark '+'.

```
<xsl:choose>
 <xsl:when test="string(field[@id='9'])">
    <xsl:value-of select="number(substring(field[@id='10'], 1,7))"/>
 </xsl:when>
 <xsl:when test="string(field[@id='11'])">
    <xsl:value-of select="number(substring(field[@id='12'], 1,7))"/>
 </xsl:when>
 <xsl:when test="string(field[@id='17'])">
    <xsl:value-of select="number(substring(field[@id='17'], 1,7))"/>
 </xsl:when>
</xsl:choose>
```

maybe there is more right decision?

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete and short solution that is completely in the spirit of XSLT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The proper XSLT way of doing this** (push style processing):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>


 <xsl:template match="field[contains('|9|13|19|', concat('|',@id, '|'))]">
  <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(.,'+')"/>
  <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the provided XML document** (corrected from being severely malformed):

```
<t>
    <line id="1">
        <field id="12"><![CDATA[6256812+0000140000000990000000000009900000000004058002C]]></field>
    </line>
    <line id="2">
        <field id="9"><![CDATA[6256813+0000040000000890000000000008900000000003648002C]]></field>
    </line>
    <line id="3">
        <field id="13"><![CDATA[6256812+0000060000000750000000000007500000000003074002C]]></field>
    </line>
    <line id="4">
        <field id="19"><![CDATA[6256837+0000010000000650000000000006500000000002664003C]]></field>
    </line>
</t>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
6256813
6256812
6256837
```

**Do note**: There is not even a single conditional xslt instruction in the transformation.

Comment: Thank you Dimitre. I will try to use it.

Comment: @Dimitre: The value being obtained is NOT always from the same field being matched. For example, the first `<xsl:when>` checks for the existence of `field[@id='9']`, but the `<xsl:value-of` element selects from `field[@id='10']`. @Petras: Is this intentional, or is there an error in your attempted XSLT?

Comment: @Flynn1179: Yes, I noticed this, but this is not explained and there appears to be no logic when to get the previous field or not, so I concluded this must be an error in the problem description.

Comment: @Dimitre: +1 For pattern matching.

Comment: @Flynn1179: It could be a "one `field` per `line`" logic... But, again, it would be more semantically meaningful to use all this logic in the pattern.

Comment: @Flybb1179: that I wrote is working. But i looking more professional decision. Now data comes like i wrote. of course I didn't noticed that others fields can also be filled but without symbol '+'

Answer (score 1):

Use the `substring-before` function. You can use it to get the text before the first `+`

I'd also recommend using a separate template for each condition:

```
<xsl:template match="field[@id='9']">
  <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(../field[@id='10'],'+')" />
</xsl:template>
```

Or something similar depending on the context.

Comment: now I'm taking information from all fields not only from field's where is symbol '+'. so how can I envelope this <xsl:template match="field[@id='9']">, which show from that field start to take data.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a bad, brittle design to me.  If you're going to rely on positional logic to parse the record, why not abandon XML and use EDI or another record-based format?

You're not using XML for what it's good for here.  Tags are metadata that describe the stream.  You lost it when you went to this design.

I'd recommend either using XML in a better way or going all the way to a position-based record scheme.

Comment: I'm not unsderstood you. but try to comment. for me data comes in line, parser generate it to xml, and I have in different fields data it depends how symbol we have in line before parsing. Yesterday i didn't wrote that others fields also are filled. now I correct it.

Comment: I'm saying that the people who generate your data didn't do a good job of designing the XML they're sending you.